# Is there a way to save a map without also exiting it?

Tags: terraria

Is there a way to save a Terraria map without also exiting the map?  Last night I was victim to a power outage that lost me a lot of work.  I'd like to avoid this in the future, but it seems overly complicated to be forced to exit just to save my progress.  Ideally, there would be some sort of autosave solution that doesn't require me to remember (since I probably won't), but anything's better than having to exit and open the map again just to save.

Comment: I would go to the terrariaonline.com forums and post this request under the Suggestion Forums, Red/Blue do look there and this seems like a good suggestion.

Comment: @James Good point.  After quickly looking, it seems that it's already been asked: http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/autosaving-in-game-saving.6165/ - I'll keep an eye on that thread and maybe I'll get an answer through it as well

Comment: Sounds like a good self-answer to me :)

Comment: Autosaving singleplayer has been added as of 1.0.4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In [Terraria 1.0.4](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/1-0-4-change-log.25667/) devs added an auto save option:

> - Added an option to automatically save the world every 10 minutes. Defaults to on.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I usually use a server to save my world without exiting the game. Even if I'm playing in single player.

I create a server with my world before I start playing, then, when I need to save the world, I type "save" in the server's cmd window.

The server also autosaves the world at regular intervals.

Comment: So, since the server now saves automatically, doesn't the client too? Would be rather silly if it didn't.

Comment: don't know, during single player game there isn't any notification that like "game saved" or something else...